# What are 'recursive data types' in Python, as referenced by the shelve doc?

Tags: python, shelve

The `shelve` package doc paragraph below mentions the term ("recursive data types"). What does "recursive data type" mean in Python?

What I know is that the word recursive means to return something.
for example:
The `sorted()` built-in function returns a value, the value is a sorted list.

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object. The difference with
>   “dbm” databases is that the values (not the keys!) in a shelf can be
>   essentially arbitrary Python objects — anything that the pickle module
>   can handle. This includes most class instances, **recursive data types**,
>   and objects containing lots of shared sub-objects. The keys are
>   ordinary strings.

Comment: in python there is no such data type, why did you decide that it is?

Comment: I've edited my question just recently please check out.

Comment: I think they mean 'nested' data types.

Comment: give a link to this resource

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shelve.html

Comment: @Ronald, yes maybe

Comment: What you "know" is wrong, please read up on recursion - StackOverflow is not the place to ask for definitions (I know you're not, but that's the question you should be asking and the answer is elsewhere) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion - as for what a recursive data type is (same issue) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type

Comment: jamaal: edit the clarifications and URLs into your question itself (click the Edit button, if you have enough rep to see it), rather than in comments, which are not indexed, searcahable, and short-lived/ may get deleted.

Comment: This is a good question and the downvotes and votes-to-close are not merited. Since people are disputing the `shelve` documentation, I edited the question and title to move that citation to the top.

Comment: @smci: This question shows a clear lack of research effort, as it can be easily answered by googling the term in question. As such, downvotes are warranted.

Comment: Actually I'm missing a down-voted comment here (if I remember well).

Comment: Acually Python *does* have recursive data structures: `x = [], x.append(x)` => [[...]]. Now `id(x) == id(x[0])` !!! Recursion is all about self-reference, which is obviously the case here!

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: a) the clear intent of the OP was to get an answer specific to Python with specific Python examples, not an abstract academic essay b) "but google hits exist for the term" does not answer the question, because many of the hits are confused/wrong/incomplete, nor do they point to official Python doc, which doesn't adequately address the term. **Glaring example, `collections.defaultdict()` is sometimes recursive and sometimes not, depends on whether its `default_factory` is self-referential. Yet you won't even find the word 'recursive' on the `defaultdict` manpage.**

Comment: The [Python doc itself doesn't mention 'recursive data type' once](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=recursion&check_keywords=yes&area=default), let alone list specific data types, and only has passing references to the concept of recursion. The dupe target you mention is not directly related and gives C examples, not Python. At minimum that target needs a Python-specific answer added.